# Unable to update and save web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, web-config

I tried to encrypt the connection string section of the web.config file of a ASP.Net Web application 
via a simple winforms application. 
I ran the VS2010 as an administrator and ran the following section of code.

```
private void encryptButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Configuration config = GetConfiguration();
            ConfigurationSection configSection = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            if (configSection != null)
                // Only encrypt the section if it is not already protected
                if (!configSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
                {
                    configSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(
                        "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
                    configSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                    config.Save();
                    DisplayWebConfig();
                }
        }

private Configuration GetConfiguration() 
        {
            var configFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\CN\R13 new\Websites\ABC");
            var vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(configFile.DirectoryName,true,configFile.Name);
            var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
            wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/",vdm);
            return WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
        }
```

As I had only the physical path I tried to map the path accordingly to a virtual path. But config.Save() is throwing me the following error

```
ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled.

Unable to save config to file 'C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\CN\R13 new\Websites\ABC'.
```

Just for the sake of clarity this is how the StackTrace looks like

```
 at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.ReplaceFile(String Source, String Target)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.Complete(String filename, Boolean success)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticWriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.UpdateConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll)
   at System.Configuration.Configuration.SaveAsImpl(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceSaveAll)
   at System.Configuration.Configuration.Save()
   at EncryptionandDecryptionApplication.Form1.encryptButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\CN\EncryptionandDecryptionApplication\EncryptionandDecryptionApplication\Form1.cs:line 55
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at EncryptionandDecryptionApplication.Program.Main() in C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\CN\EncryptionandDecryptionApplication\EncryptionandDecryptionApplication\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: "ABC" is strange name for config file for a web site. Usually it is "web.config"... Make sure your actual code specify file path.

Comment: running VS as administrator doesn't make the internal web host in vs2010 run as administrator. Double check that the actual location of the file is somewhere it would have rights (like in its deployment directory)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov .. should is not be the path to web.config ? Then it should not contain ideally the ..\web.config at the end right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is perfect. There seems to be permission issue. Just for time being try giving full access to your file location to everyone. If it works then its the permission issue(Though giving full permission to everyone isn't a good idea )

If you want to add UAC permission in your application then you can add app.manifest file and in that file changes the requestedExecutionLevel tag as below:

```
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: Could yo please look at the Stack Trace I have just appended  ? Thanks

Comment: This error is because of restricted user privileges under Windows 7. It should work with elevated UAC permissions.

Comment: Just Try giving full permision to that file and test it.. then you can add UAC permission within your application.

Comment: Thanks :) Helped a lot

Comment: Welcome. If you want to add UAC permission in your application then you can add app.manifest file and in that file changes the requestedExecutionLevel tag as below:                             <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />